# How do i create a discord link like discord.com/invite/xxxxx

Tags: discord

[Discord.com/invite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYQI1.png)

I tried creating an account and thought it would come exactly like discord.com/invite but if you where to custom the link it would come as discord.gg/ but im looking for how to make it discord.com/invite/xxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Right click the server in question, navigate to "Invite People" and copy the generated link. Once done, your link will look something like this: `https://discord.gg/xxxxxxx`

You'll want to replace it with `https://discord.com/invite/xxxxxxx` instead, of course replacing the Xs with your actual invite code.